# Deserializing JSON into an object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON:

```
{
    "foo" : [ 
        { "bar" : "baz" },
        { "bar" : "qux" }
    ]
}
```

And I want to deserialize this into a collection. I have defined this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(jsonString);
```

How can I deserialize my JSON?

Comment: This is meant as a canonical question for _"Why doesn't this deserialization work"_, and supposed to show a general workflow people could follow. Feel free to answer, improve and use as a duplicate target.

Answer (score 23):

That JSON is not a `Foo` JSON array. The code `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString)` will parse the JSON string **from the root on up**, and your type `T` must match that JSON structure exactly. The parser is not going to guess *which* JSON member is supposed to represent the `List<Foo>` you're looking for.

You need a root object, that represents the JSON from the root element.

You can easily let the classes to do that be generated from a sample JSON. To do this, copy your JSON and click `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes` in Visual Studio.

Alternatively, you could do the same on http://json2csharp.com, which generates more or less the same classes.

You'll see that the collection actually is one element deeper than expected:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string bar { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Foo> foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize the JSON from the root (and be sure to rename `RootObject` to something useful):

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

And access the collection:

```
foreach (var foo in rootObject.foo)
{
    // foo is a `Foo`

}
```

You can always rename properties to follow your casing convention and apply a `JsonProperty` attribute to them:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure that the JSON contains enough sample data. The class parser will have to guess the appropriate C# type based on the contents found in the JSON.

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster.  Though I couldn't find the paste special option in VS2010 nor VS2017, the provided link did the job.  Wow.  Wish I'd known about this site earlier on.  THANK YOU!