# When defining a class that extends a list, how can I refer to the list from its inner methods?

Tags: c#, oop

Say that I have a `public class MyClass: List<MyObjects>`.

I want this class to have an inner method that manipulates the list, say

```
void ConstructListFromJSON(){
 HoweverIshouldrefertomylist = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<MyObjects>("myObjects.json");
}
```

What should I put in place of the HoweverIshouldrefertomylist ? I've tried `this`, `self` and similar but it doesn't work. Surely there's a way to refer to the data strucure in the list?

Comment: I think you actually should be using [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @juharr Yeah this is probably not the perfect solution for my current problem, but regardless,  is there any way to do this reference? Out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reassign `this`, so clear the list and add whatever you want to add:

```
var objectsToStore = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<MyObjects>>("myObjects.json");
this.Clear();
this.AddRange(objectsToStore);
```

But in general, you really don't want to inherit from `List<T>`. See [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt). Use composition instead:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<YourObjects> YourObjects { get; set; } 

    public void ConstructListFromJSON()
    {
        YourObjects = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<MyObjects>("myObjects.json");
    }   
}
```

To properly generate classes representing your JSON, see [Deserializing JSON into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222588/deserializing-json-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

To access a base object, just use the base keyword. But, for what you are showing, a different approach makes more sense - - just maintain a private object reference.

```
 public class foo{

    private List<MyObject> myList = null;

    public foo(List<MyObject> l){
      myList = l;
    }

 }
```

Now, the class has the list upon construction, but the list is private to the user.  This is a better form of design. It uses composition over inheritance and provides a more loosely coupled design.