# SerializeObject, DeserializeObject and return Json

Tags: c#, json

I have little problem with deserialization. In variable test I get null. Other thing how return correct json in method.

*In picture I cast to object but normally I cast to ClaimValue :)

Have you got any idea what I made wrong?

```
       foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            claimValues.Add(new ClaimValue { Type = claim.Type, Value = claim.Value, ValueType = claim.ValueType });
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            results = claimValues
        });

        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClaimValue>(json);

        return json;
    }
}

public class ClaimValue
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrapping the claims list in an anonymous object, so your JSON will look like this:

```
{
    "results" : [
        { 
            "Type" : "foo",
            "ValueType" : "bar",
            "Value" : "baz"
        },
        {
            // ...
        }
    ]
}
```

You cannot deserialize that as one `ClaimsValue`, because that doesn't match that structure.

Generate classes to contain the wrapper and the list, something like this:

```
public class ClaimsContainer
{
    public List<ClaimsValue> results { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize into that:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClaimsContainer>(json);
```

See also [Deserializing JSON into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222588/deserializing-json-into-an-object).

Comment: 6 minutes :) and I will accept your answer :) thanks!