# Deserializing a JSON to c# object when key contains dollar($)(Metadata)

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

So i'm getting a response like this

```
{"$id":"1","success":true,"errors":{"$id":"2","$values":[]}}
```

how can i convert this into to a c# object, tried using this(http://json2csharp.com/) tool to make an output but it doesn't make sense
this is what i'm getting

```
x

public class Errors
{
    public string __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public List<object> __invalid_name__$values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

I'm kinda new to c#, any inputs would be deeply appreciated, i basically need access to success key variable

Comment: duplicate : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222588/deserializing-json-into-an-object]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222588/deserializing-json-into-an-object)

Comment: why do you think, this classes are doesn't make sense?

Comment: i added my answer with output. view it might be it help you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `[JsonProperty]` attribute to every property that key name started with dollar `$`

```
public class Errors
{
    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$values")]
    public List<object> values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

Because the $ indicates metadata, not an actual data field. so you have to modify your `JsonSerializerSettings` to ignore MetadataPropertyHandling.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
```

And finally deserialize your json to above class objects.

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, settings);
```

Here I created a sample console app for demonstration purpose that shows how above code will work.

```
class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json file");

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, settings);

        Console.WriteLine("id: " + rootObject.id);
        Console.WriteLine("success: " + rootObject.success);
        Console.WriteLine("errors.id: " + rootObject.errors.id);
        Console.WriteLine("errors.values: " + string.Join(",", rootObject.errors.values));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: glad to hear and welocme :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, What you can do is

```
public class Errors
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$values")]
    public List<object> values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your object attributes to match you json string ($id instead of _invalid_name_$id), then you can use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class  to serialize json string from object or to object (T). May de/serialize array(list) of objects.

```
public class HelperSerializer<T> where T: class
{ 
    public static string WriteFromObject(T source)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())            {  
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, source);
            byte[] json = ms.ToArray();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);
        }
    }

    // Deserialize a JSON stream to an object.  
    public static T ReadToObject(string json)
    {          

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return ser.ReadObject(ms) as T;
        }
    }

}
```

Use `persons = HelperSerializer<List<Person>>.ReadToObject(json);
and var json = HelperSerializer<List<Person>>.WriteFromObject(persons);`