# How can I deserialize JSON, which contains a root element; footer element and irrelevant data?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am looking at some JSON data, which looks like this (the data values are hypothetical):

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "Class": "Mr Smith",
            "Student": [
                "Mark Williams",
                15,
                "1 The Street London",
                "Maths",
                "Football",
                "Tennis"
            ]
        },
    {
            "Class": "Ms Morgan",
            "Student": [
                "Jenny Phillips",
                12,
                "1 The Farm London",
                "English",
                "Netball",
                "Football"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

I am trying to get the students into a class, which looks something like this:

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name {get; set}
   public int Age {get; set}
   public string Address {get; set}
}
```

Notice the following:

1) There is a root element (Students), which is irrelevant.
2) There is what appears to be a footer element (total), which is irrelevant.  What is the correct terminology for the "footer" element?
3) Address; favourite subject; favourite sport and least favourite sport are irrelevant i.e. only name; age and address are relevant.

I have spent the last few hours trying to get this work with Newtonsoft e.g. I have tried this:

```
List<Student> students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
```

How can I deserialise this with Newtonsoft? Ihave spent the last three hours trying to do this, but haven't managed it.

Comment: Well you have multiple students, so you'll need a collection of some sort for them, not a single `Student` object.

Comment: Your example json is invalid.

Comment: @ Broots Waymb, please see my update.  I was obviously a little lazy.

Comment: @w0051977 did you check out [this page](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)? I only glanced over it (as I am also lazy), but it seems like it might address your use case.

Comment: @Guru Stron , thanks.  I have updated the json.  I was copying and pasting part of the extract (and changing the values).  The entire extract is large.

Comment: The root element, `students` is *not* irrelevant. It is the container for your individual `student` objects

Comment: @Jonathan, not relevant to the class.  I realise it is important to the json.

Comment: @Guru Stron , I have added a further update.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brian Rogers, please see my update.  Wrote the question too quickily.

Comment: your class should be `public class Student
    {
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public IList<object> Student { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public IList<Student> students { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222588/deserializing-json-into-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to get the data into your list of students:

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);

List<Student> students = jo["students"]
    .Select(t => t["Student"])
    .Select(s => new Student
    {
        Name = (string)s[0],
        Age = (int)s[1],
        Address = (string)s[2]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GzS9vj

Answer (score 0):

You can write Custom Json Converter as per the requirement. You may take help from newtonsoft site:  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm